# How can i capture my cameraview and my customview over camera simultaneously android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-custom-view

I am making an app in which i am opening a camera and above the camera i am drawing a flower picture from a custom view canvas object. Now i want to take picture what should i do to take picture of camera with that flower.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this layout for that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/layoutCam">

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgHole" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Take Snap" 
    android:id="@+id/btnTakeSnap"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and java code is

```
 public void onClick(View v)
        {
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,  postViewCallback, jpegCallback);
            chal();
        }

private boolean chal()
        {
            buttonTakeSnap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            View v1 = camView.getChildAt(1);
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            v1.buildDrawingCache();
            bmp = v1.getDrawingCache();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            buttonTakeSnap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Akhtitaam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
```

using this code i got two bitmaps one from chal(); method and second from jpegCallBack(); method now you can put these bitmaps on a same layout to overlap and capture that view

Using this code

Use this method to capture views

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v)
{
  Paint drawPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
  drawPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
  drawPaint.setFilterBitmap(false);
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
  c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, drawPaint);
  v.draw(c);
  return b;
}
```

pass your camera's surface view as a parameter like this

```
View view=(YourParentLayout) findViewById(R.id.YourParentLayout);
loadBitmapFromView(view);
```

Comment: Hello But it will show Only Ui but not camera, i want to capture UI(Flower) and cameraview simultaneouly

Comment: i think your camera and flowers are both in same layout so please pass your parent layout as view

Comment: yes i tried the same, still no luck, actually surfaceview shows black screen.and i am able to see only flower.

Comment: i think your answer willbe helpful for my problem, i understand that i can have two bitmap but after that you answer is not understandable, please make some changes in your code(IF POSSIBLE), And also which view will hold camera preview in your XML.?

Comment: And also i will be able to move flower above camera screen, then how would i use the position of cartoon(Xpos,Ypos) to make a exact location of camera image+flower image.